# Problemas com ReactiveForms no Angular

Tags: angular, formulário

Olá, eu estou com uma dificuldade em encontrar a solução do meu problema sendo assim estou aqui, estou tentando criar um campo de pesquisa ná minha página, ele não está fazendo a pesquisa, porém não está me retornando nenhum erro no build nem no console, então estou perdido se me esqueci de algum passo ou import de algum modulo, não sei, me ajudem porfavor, segue o código:

## servicos.service.ts

```
import {HttpClient, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

import {Servico} from './servico/servico.model';
import {AUTONOMOUS_API} from '../app.api';

@Injectable()
export class ServicosService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  servicos(search?: string): Observable<Servico[]> {
    let params: HttpParams;
    if (search) {
      params = new HttpParams().append('q', search);
    }
    return this.http.get<Servico[]>(`${AUTONOMOUS_API}/autonomos/`, {params: params});
  }

  servicosById(id: string): Observable<Servico> {
    return this.http.get<Servico>(`${AUTONOMOUS_API}/autonomos/${id}/`);
 }
}
```

## servicos.component.html

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="header-content" align="center">
     <h1>Catálogo de Serviços</h1>
     <br>

    <mdc-form-field [formGroup]="searchForm" fluid class="form">
      <mdc-text-field formControlName="searchControl" outlined label="Pesquisar" [mdcElevation]="3">
        <mdc-icon mdcTextFieldIcon leading>search</mdc-icon>
      </mdc-text-field>
    </mdc-form-field>
  </div>

  <div class="row">

  <div *ngFor="let servico of servicos" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <app-servico [servico]="servico"></app-servico>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

## servicos.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {Servico} from './servico/servico.model';
import {ServicosService} from './servicos.service';

import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {catchError, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {from} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-servicos',
  templateUrl: './servicos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./servicos.component.scss']
})
export class ServicosComponent implements OnInit {
  servicos: Servico[];

  searchForm: FormGroup;
  searchControl: FormControl;

  constructor(private servicosService: ServicosService,
              private fb: FormBuilder) { }

   ngOnInit() {
    this.searchControl = this.fb.control('');
    this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
      searchControl: this.searchControl
    });

    this.searchControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(searchTerm => this.servicosService.servicos(searchTerm)
          .pipe(
            catchError(error => from([]))
          )
        )
      ).subscribe(dados => this.servicos = dados);

    this.servicosService.servicos().subscribe(dados => this.servicos = dados);

  }
}
```

## app.module.ts

Meu app.module está grande então vou mandar os principais para o ReactiveForms

```
// DEFAULT
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {CommonModule, HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

// COMPONENTS
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DialogLoginComponent } from './dialog-login/dialog-login.component';
import { DialogContateComponent } from './dialog-contate/dialog-contate.component';
// SERVICES
import {ServicosService} from './servicos/servicos.service';
// REACTIVE FORMS
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
. . .
imports: [
  CommonModule,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule
],
providers: [
  ServicosService,
  {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
],
entryComponents: [
  DialogLoginComponent,
  DialogContateComponent
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

## servicos.component.ts (ATUALIZADO)

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 import {Servico} from './servico/servico.model';
 import {ServicosService} from './servicos.service';

 import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
 import {catchError, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
 import {from} from 'rxjs';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-servicos',
   templateUrl: './servicos.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./servicos.component.scss']
 })
 export class ServicosComponent implements OnInit {
  servicos: Servico[];

  searchForm = new FormGroup({
  searchControl: new FormControl('')
 });

  constructor(private servicosService: ServicosService,
              private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
     searchControl: ['']
   });

    this.searchForm.get('searchControl').valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(searchTerm => 
this.servicosService.servicos(searchTerm)
          .pipe(
            catchError(error => from([]))
          )
         )
      ).subscribe(dados => this.servicos = dados);

    this.servicosService.servicos().subscribe(dados => this.servicos = dados);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você na criou a instancia do FormGroup da maneira correta.

`searchForm = new FormGroup({
    searchControl: new FormControl('')
  });`

Veja a documentação completa em: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-1-creating-a-formgroup-instance

Comment: Olhe no final do post ja atualizado, não funciona ainda.

Answer (score 0):

faz assim:

```
export class ServicosComponent implements OnInit {
  servicos: Servico[];
  searchForm: FormGroup;

    get search(){
    return this.searchForm.get('searchControl');
    }

  constructor(private servicosService: ServicosService,
              private fb: FormBuilder) { }

   ngOnInit() {
    this.searchControl = this.fb.control('');
    this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
      searchControl: ['']
    });

    this.search.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(searchTerm => this.servicosService.servicos(searchTerm)
          .pipe(
            catchError(error => from([]))
          )
        )
      ).subscribe(dados => this.servicos = dados);

    this.servicosService.servicos().subscribe(dados => this.servicos = dados);

  }
}
```

Comment: Aqui não está instanciando o `searchControl`, então quando chama o `this.searchControl` da erro.

Comment: Ou vc faz     get searchControl ou this.search

Comment: continua não funcionando, de uma olhada no final do post com o arquivo atualizado

Comment: Tem algum erro no console? Ve se na aba network ele ta fazendo a chamada http.

Comment: Bom o console está normla sem erros, apenas a mensagem de produção do angular, já na aba network não sei exatamente o que você quer que eu veja ele faz chamada dos arquivos normais pelo que olhei

Comment: Edita sua pergunta com o codigo do servicosService

Comment: Pronto editado!